Camera back webrtc
I use a webrtc application and I want to switch between the two cameras but when I try to activate, nothing happens and the camera is not displayed
function broadcastNewCameraTracks(stream, type, mirrorMode = true) {
    h.setLocalStream(stream, mirrorMode);

    let track = type == 'audio' ? stream.getAudioTracks()[0] : s                    tream.getVideoTracks()[0];
            
    for (let p in pc) {
        if (pc.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            let pName = pc[p];

            if (typeof pName == 'object' && pName.replaceTrack) {
                pName.replaceTrack(track);
            }
        }
    }
}


document.getElementById('camera-rotate').addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let elem = document.getElementById('camera-rotate');
    let usingRearCamera = elem.getAttribute('data-using-rear-camera') === 'true';
    let onPath = elem.querySelector('path.on');
    let offPath = elem.querySelector('path.off');

    if (myStream) {
        myStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
    }

    try {
        const desiredCamera = usingRearCamera ? "user" : "environment";

        if (desiredCamera) {
            const constraints = {
                video: {
                    // width: { max: 800 },
                    // height: { max: 720 },
                    // frameRate: { ideal: 15 },
                    // bitrate: 500000, // Réduire le débit binaire à 500 Kbps
                    facingMode: { ideal: desiredCamera } // Utilisez 'ideal' pour éviter les erreurs si la caméra n'est pas disponible
                },
                audio: true // Optionnel, si vous avez besoin de l'audio aussi
            };

            const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);

            myStream = stream;

            // Diffuse les nouvelles pistes vidéo et audio
            broadcastNewCameraTracks(myStream, 'video', true);

            // Met à jour l'état de la caméra et l'interface utilisateur
            usingRearCamera = !usingRearCamera;
            elem.setAttribute('data-using-rear-camera', usingRearCamera);

            if (usingRearCamera) {
                onPath.classList.remove('on');
                onPath.classList.add('off');
                offPath.classList.remove('off');
                offPath.classList.add('on');
                elem.classList.add('camera-off');
                elem.setAttribute('title', 'Activer la caméra avant');
            } else {
                onPath.classList.remove('off');
                onPath.classList.add('on');
                offPath.classList.remove('on');
                offPath.classList.add('off');
                elem.setAttribute('title', 'Deactivate Rear Camera');
                elem.classList.remove('camera-off');
            }
        } else {
            console.error('No appropriate camera found.');
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error accessing camera:', error);
    }
});


In my demo you can switch the camera from user camera to enviroment  camera,
you can try it
https://vrobbi-webrtc-demo.glitch.me/uploadvideo
code referencing the issue
const supported = navigator.mediaDevices.getSupportedConstraints().facingMode;

if (supported == true) {

  var constraints = {
    audio: true,
    video: {
      facingMode: document.getElementById('frontorenvironment').value
    }
  };

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(
    constraints
  ).then(
    successCallback,
    errorCallback
  );

} else {
  //alert('non   supportato');


  var constraints = {
    audio: true,
    video: true
  };

  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(
    constraints
  ).then(
    successCallback,
    errorCallback
  );

}

document.getElementById('frontorenvironment').onchange = function (e) {
  if (supported == true) {
    console.log('Supportato facingmode');
    window.stream.getVideoTracks().forEach(function (track) {
      track.stop();


    });

    constraints.video.facingMode = document.getElementById('frontorenvironment').value;

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(
      constraints).then(
        successCallback,
        errorCallback
      );

  }


}

